# Backbone Collection get(id) method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have one main home page in my application and another page for each post that can be accessed through a list displayed in the home page..

this is how my router looks like :

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.model = new model();
        this.collection = new collection();
    },


    routes: {
        "" : "showForm",
        "post/:id" : "showPost"
    },


    showPost: function(id){
        var curmodel = this.collection.get(id);
        var post = new postView({model:curmodel});
        post.render();
        $(".maincontainer").html(post.el);

    },

    showForm : function(){
        var qcView = new qcV({model:this.model, collection:this.collection});
        qcView.render()
        $(".maincontainer").html(qcView.el);
    }
});
```

this is what one of the links to the posts in this list looks like

```
<h2><a id= "<%=_id%>" href="#post/<%=_id%>"><%=name%></h2></a>
```

my first question is: Is it dangerous to link pages with a hash-based URL in this manner?

my second question is: I am having no problem navigating to a posts view if I click one of the links in my home page. I my url successfully changes to something like `http://127.0.0.1:3000/#post/51ffdb93c29eb6cc17000034` and that specific post's view is rendered. However at that point if I refresh the page, or if I directly type `http://127.0.0.1:3000/#post/51ffdb93c29eb6cc17000034`to my URL bar the `this.collection.get(id)` method in my showPost method in the router returns `undefined`. Can anyone help me figure out why this is the case?

I checked couple times that my initialize method gets called both times, and my collection and model is created successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #2, you are most likely not fetching the collection on the "post" route. Try fetching the collection (if it does not exist) and then call render. That should do the trick!

Comment: its really interesting because the collection exists, I can see it when I print it in my console.. I can even see the model that i am looking for

Comment: We're obviously missing something important. Where are you fetching your data?

Answer (score 2):

I think @Trunal's on the right path for the 2nd question. For the first, no, it's not "dangerous". You're not really doing anything different than you would with a classic server-side app, passing information to the server via GET to retrieve info. In my opinion, this should be the preferred approach to implementing routes (rather than attempting to trigger `backbone.history.navigate` manually, as it avoids all kinds of setup and eventing issues that might otherwise occur).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i am pretty sure there is something else going on with the 2nd question. even if I try to open the link in a new tab from the list it doesnt render the post

Comment: @trunal sorry you guys were totally right.. I just had to put my code inside this.collection.fetch().complete(function(){});